# Shapiro-Wilk Output

Tags: t-test, dataset, normality-assumption

I have data comprised into different variables (between females and males, measurements of body fat through 3 different methods) and after running a shapiro-wilk test, the output tells me parts of the data are normally distributed and other parts are not normally distributed. This is an uni assignment, so we're directed into assuming shapiro-wilk test is what we should use to assume normality.

Aim of the study is: 
To investigate the validity of anthropometric measures for the estimation of body fat percentage using the BodPod as the gold standard.

Objectives: 
- Identify how measurements differ according to sex. -Describe your sample population using the appropriate reference categories for each measure. 
- Assess how classification of each measure compares with that of the BodPod

[image]

I have non normal data for Bodpod Male and Ratio Female. I don't really know what to do next. I know which tests I should run if all the data were normally or not normally distributed, but since this is not the case, I don't know if  should split data and run different tests or not.

Comment: I'm afraid we can't tell you what to do next, either, because you have not explained your study objective.  If you would like to expand your question to include that information, I'm sure you would get great advice.

Comment: I will elaborate the aim of the asignment, Thank you!